# Java Multithreading Uppercase String

Tags: java, multithreading

I have one string: "abcdef", and 3 threads: t1, t2 and t3. I want them to return the string capitalized: "ABCDEF" (the order of characters doesn't matter). I managed to capitalize the string 3 times. I want it all to happen only once. This is the main class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Thread t1 = new Thread(new CapitalizeString("Thread 1", "abcdef"));
    Thread t2 = new Thread(new CapitalizeString("Thread 2", "abcdef"));
    Thread t3 = new Thread(new CapitalizeString("Thread 3", "abcdef"));

    t1.start();
    t2.start();
    t3.start();

}
```

And this is the class used for uppercase:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class CapitalizeString implements Runnable {
String list;
String nameThread;

public CapitalizeString(String name, String str) {
    nameThread = name;
    list = str;
}

public void capitalize() {
    char[] arr = list.toCharArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < list.length(); i++) {
        arr[i] = Character.toUpperCase(arr[i]);
        System.out.println("Thread-ul " + nameThread + " solved " + arr[i]);
    }
    System.out.print("\n");
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        capitalize();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to split the work between the threads so each thread capitalizes only part of the string?

Comment: If you want it only once, why are you using 3 threads?

Comment: Could be for improving performance, if he has a really long string and wants 3 threads working together on capitalizing it.

Comment: @potato, i want to split the work, yes. For example, t1 capitalizes a, t2 capitalizes c and d and so on...

Comment: Each thread iterates over all elements of `arr`.  Consider passing something like a `beginIndex` and `endIndex` for each thread so a thread iterates only over a subset of `arr`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: just using `String str = "abcdef".toUpperCase();` is much faster for short strings (on my computer the multithreaded code starts working faster when the string is ~50000 characters long).

The string is split into a char array (`chars`). Each thread iterates through the array `chars`, converts one letter to uppercase, and skips 2 letters for the other threads to deal with. When all threads are done, the array is turned back into a `String`.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    String str = "abcdef";
    System.out.println(str);
    char[] chars = str.toCharArray();

    Thread t1 = new Thread(new CapitalizeString(chars, 0, 3));
    Thread t2 = new Thread(new CapitalizeString(chars, 1, 3));
    Thread t3 = new Thread(new CapitalizeString(chars, 2, 3));

    t1.start();
    t2.start();
    t3.start();

    // wait until all threads finish their work
    try{
        t1.join();
        t2.join();
        t3.join();
    }catch(InterruptedException e){ }

    // print the result
    str = String.valueOf(chars);
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

class CapitalizeString:

```
public class CapitalizeString implements Runnable {

    char[] chars;
    int start;
    int numThreads;

    public CapitalizeString(char[] chars, int startIndex, int numThreads) {
        this.chars = chars;
        this.numThreads = numThreads;
        start = startIndex;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for(int x = start; x < chars.length; x += numThreads){
            chars[x] = Character.toUpperCase(chars[x]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any reason to check if the thread is alive before calling join?

Comment: To avoid calling `join()` on a thread that isn't alive anymore, which would throw an exception. You can't guarantee that `t1` will finish executing before `t2`.

Comment: @potato You can't guarantee that the thread won't stop between checking if it's alive and calling join, but fortunately it doesn't matter. join() returns if the thread is dead.

Comment: The thing about this is that it's not really doing multithreading in the sense that each thread is getting the next piece of work in a synchronized fashion. Here each thread has knowledge of the other threads because they are each doing every third character. A proper example would have the Capitalize class providing the next character with synchronized method.

Comment: @K.Nicholas Fair point, the threads are indeed "aware" of the other threads, but it is required here to avoid synchronization which is bad for performance, if you want the threads working in parallel it isn't a wise choice to make them "wait in line" to get the next piece of data to process. I edited the code a little so now the number of threads is inputted via the constructor instead of being hard-coded into the thread's function.

Comment: @PeterLawrey you're right, my bad, thanks for pointing it out. I corrected the code.

Answer (score 3):

This will not only be much more complicated but many times slower. However, as an exercise, I suggest using the simplest approach which is to use a parallelStream

```
String upper = "abcdef".chars().parallel()
        .map(Character::toUpperCase)
        .mapToObj(c -> Character.toString((char) c))
        .collect(Collectors.joining());
System.out.println(upper);
```

You might wonder, why is this so much slower? Consider this at a human scale, you could either

a) convert the letters by hand on paper, or

b) you can send three letters to three friends asking them to mail you two letters in uppercase each.

Except it's worse that because the threads have to be started first which takes even longer so really is it

c) find three new friends who are willing answers your letters and then b)

Comment: Using a stream makes the code short and neat but adds overhead which makes it run slower (and uses a lot more memory which is bad for processing very large inputs). I don't use streams at all when I need to maximize performance.

Comment: @potato streams can be ass efficient as loops and since it re-uses a thread pool, the speed entirely depends on whether this pool has started already or not.

Comment: streams can be just as fast as custom code, but their performance depends on many things that you should consider before deciding if you should use a stream or not, including: 1)) whether a function requires synchronization between threads (with custom code you can avoid or minimize the need for synchronization, which streams aren't optimized to do). 2)) how much work you perform on the collection (for small tasks like capitalizing chars, the stream will spend most of the time manipulating the input data structure, while custom code can avoid it altogether).

Comment: you don't have to take my word for it, do some benchmarking and see for yourself, you can use the code from our answers here for example.

Answer (score 0):

Right, the question was modified after I put a response in the first time and now there is an accepted answer but I just felt like commenting anyway. This might be considered a more complete example because `CapitalizeWorker` threads are getting work to do from the `CapitalizeJob` class and putting results back. I think it's a better example because it doesn't depend a specific number of threads but instead is optimized for however many cores your system has. It is also shutting down and waiting for the results in a clean manner. Just my $.02 worth.

```
private void run() throws InterruptedException {
    CapitalizeJob capitalizeJob = new CapitalizeJob("abcdef");
    int processors = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
    ExecutorService executors = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(processors);
    for ( int t = 0; t < processors; ++t) {
        executors.execute(new CapitalizeWorker(capitalizeJob));
    }
    executors.shutdown(); // this is missing from OP thread example
    executors.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    System.out.println( capitalizeJob.getResult() );
}

public class CapitalizeWorker implements Runnable {
    private CapitalizeJob capitalizeJob;
    CapitalizeWorker(CapitalizeJob capitalizeJob) {
        this.capitalizeJob = capitalizeJob;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        char c;
        while ( (c = capitalizeJob.getNextChar()) != 0 ) {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().toString());
            capitalizeJob.setNextChar(Character.toUpperCase(c));
        }
    }
}
public class CapitalizeJob {
    private char[] arr;
    private int jobIndex;
    private char[] result;
    private int resultIndex;

    public CapitalizeJob(String name) {
        arr = name.toCharArray();
        result = new char[arr.length];
        jobIndex = 0;
        resultIndex = 0;
    }
    public synchronized char getNextChar() {
        return jobIndex < arr.length ? arr[jobIndex++] : 0 ;
    }
    public synchronized void setNextChar(char c) {
        result[resultIndex++] = c;
    }
    public String getResult() {
        return new String(result);
    }
}
```